# Can I show Toast from none-UI Service in android?

Tags: android, service, toast

I have a service which is working in background.

> How can I show Toast text message from Service that does not have UI?

*No Activity,This is none-UI service.*

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly do that. A service is a Context. So you can call

```
Toast.makeText(this, "My Information", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your background thread.

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
             Toast.makeText(context, "Running background", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been showing it from dummy classes by using the application class instance, basically what this means that you can show it anywhere within you application (includes service).

```
public class DemosApplication extends Application {

    private static DemosApplication instance;
    private Toast toast;

    public static DemosApplication getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = this;
        }
    }

    public void showToast(int resID) {
        showToast(getString(resID));
    }

    public void showToast(String text) {
        if (toast != null) {
            toast.cancel();
        }

        toast = Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Usage from anywhere

```
DemosApplication.getInstance().showToast("Lalalala");
```